# Are these winding numbers zero?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Lang's Complex Analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=WZX4GEpxPRgC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 138 he states the following definition:

> **Definition:** We say that a closed path $\gamma$ in $U$ is homologous to $0$ in $U$ if the winding number $W(\gamma,\alpha)=0$
>   for every point $\alpha$ not in $U$.

Afterwards on page 174, he states the following theorem:

> **Theorem (Residue Formula):** Let $U$ be an open set, and $\gamma$ a closed chain in $U$ such that $\gamma$ is homologous to $0$ in $U$.
>   Let $f$ be analytic on $U$ except at a finite number of point
>   $z_1,\ldots, z_n$. Let $m_i=W(\gamma,z_i)$. Then $$\int_{\gamma}f=2\pi
>  i\sum_{k=1}^n m_k\cdot Res_{z_k}f$$

So my question is the $m_i's$ in theorem isn't all zero since $\gamma$ is homologous to $0$?

Comment: The $m_k$ are in $U$.

Comment: More to the point, the $z_k$ are in $U$.

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks!

Comment: @anomaly thanks!

Comment: @LeeMosher: Er, yes, of course. The $m_i$ are just integers. :)